# How to retrieve attachment file name in display form of custom list form with SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, attachment

I have created custom list and modified display form of list for display attached image of list.
I have place HTML image control on display form but I can’t get attachment URL path which I can assign to Image control. I tried to some level hardcode like:

“http://Server Name/SiteName/Lists/ListName/Attachments/{@ID}/**???**”

I can get ID value so it can be work but the last thing file name, I am not able to get the attached file name.
Do I need to write code to get path? If yes then which event I have to inherited

Answer (score 4):

This solution requires undocumented magic.

*...puts robe and wizard hat*

Inside your table with the @Title and such:

```
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Attachments</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
      <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="attachmentsField" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Attachments" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can change the attribute ControlMode to "Edit", it shows the **Delete** option.

Comment: A little explanation, the @Attachments attribute returned by the list items only tells that the list item has one or more attachments, the actual list is a different query, luckily all the hassle is handled by the FormField control

Comment: this solution output the entire link html.  
i just want the attachment file name.

or, how can i control the output of the SharePoint:FormField tag?

Comment: That requires a way more complicate override in the control render, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.templatebasedcontrol.customtemplate.aspx